# android, calling shared prefs from another activity

Tags: android

I am making a sort of quiz app where I use the shared prefs to indicate which level you're in. Right now i used a shared pref in each single activity, but I want to make a special activity for the save function of the shared prefs which I can call from all my activities.
Here is what I did:

```
package com.flag.fun;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class lvl01Activity extends Activity   {
EditText input;
SharedPreferences someData;
public int n;
public static String fileName = "myfile";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lvl01);

    someData = getSharedPreferences(fileName, 0);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lvl01input);
    Button lvl01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lvl01check);
     lvl01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String answer = input.getText().toString();
                if(answer.contentEquals("canada") || answer.contentEquals("Canada")){
                    n = 2;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = someData.edit();
                    editor.putInt("key", n);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent lvl01Intent = new Intent("com.fun.flag.LVL01CHECK");
                    startActivity(lvl01Intent);
                }
            }
        });
}
    }
```

could the shared prefs part be an apprt class?
If yes please tell me how to call it?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class that handles all the reads and writes to the shared preference file and then create instances of that class in each activity.

```
public class PersistData {
...
...
..
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private PersistData persistData;

...
...
..




persistData = new PersistData(this);

someObject = persistData.readData();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a signle point of management to save the results and to manage the "score" use a bindService. You will be able to bind from all you activities.